# Difference bwtween [1] and [1:2] in array

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
a=([1,2], [3,4], [5,6])
b=[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
print(a[1])
print(a[1:2])
print(b[1])
print(b[1:2])
```

1. Why the `a[1]` returns a list `[3,4]`,  but `a[2:3]` returns a tuple `([3,4])`?
2. I always thought `list[1]` is the same as `list[1:2]`. But I was wrong. Why the length of `b[1]` (returns a list `[3,4]`)  is two, but the length for `b[1:2]` returns a list of list `[[3,4]]` with length 1?

Answer (score 2):

In python, the syntax `array[x:y]` slices the array from the index `x` to `y-1`. So instead of `array[x]` which return a **value** of the array, it return **the array** with only the elems from `x` to `y-1`.